# Multiple roc curves on same plot using roc()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Where am I going wrong here?

I am trying to plot two `roc` curves on the same plot using `ggplot`.

I get this error when I run the below code

```
Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot
```

ggplot which does not work

```
ggroc(roc_1) +
  ggroc(roc_2) +
  labs(title = "ROC curve", y = "Sensitivity", x = "Specificity")
```

base package which works

```
plot(roc_1, col = 1, lty = 2, main = "ROC")
plot(roc_2, col = 4, lty = 3, add = TRUE)
```

The dput is too big to post on stackoverflow so here is the structure of one of the `ROC` calculations.

I am trying to plot two ROC curves similar to below.

```
List of 15
 $ percent           : logi FALSE
 $ sensitivities     : num [1:26455] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ specificities     : num [1:26455] 0.00 4.00e-05 8.01e-05 1.20e-04 1.60e-04 ...
 $ thresholds        : num [1:26455] -Inf 0.0017 0.00189 0.00201 0.00214 ...
 $ direction         : chr "<"
 $ cases             : num [1:1540] 0.958 0.919 0.973 0.785 0.933 ...
 $ controls          : num [1:24975] 0.6604 0.026 0.1389 0.0558 0.0594 ...
 $ fun.sesp          :function (thresholds, controls, cases, direction)  
 $ auc               :Classes 'auc', 'numeric'  atomic [1:1] 0.942
  .. ..- attr(*, "partial.auc")= logi FALSE
  .. ..- attr(*, "percent")= logi FALSE
  .. ..- attr(*, "roc")=List of 15
  .. .. ..$ percent           : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..$ sensitivities     : num [1:26455] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. .. ..$ specificities     : num [1:26455] 0.00 4.00e-05 8.01e-05 1.20e-04 1.60e-04 ...
  .. .. ..$ thresholds        : num [1:26455] -Inf 0.0017 0.00189 0.00201 0.00214 ...
  .. .. ..$ direction         : chr "<"
  .. .. ..$ cases             : num [1:1540] 0.958 0.919 0.973 0.785 0.933 ...
  .. .. ..$ controls          : num [1:24975] 0.6604 0.026 0.1389 0.0558 0.0594 ...
  .. .. ..$ fun.sesp          :function (thresholds, controls, cases, direction)  
  .. .. ..$ auc               :Classes 'auc', 'numeric'  atomic [1:1] 0.942
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "partial.auc")= logi FALSE
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "percent")= logi FALSE
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "roc")=List of 8
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ percent      : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ sensitivities: num [1:26455] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ specificities: num [1:26455] 0.00 4.00e-05 8.01e-05 1.20e-04 1.60e-04 ...
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ thresholds   : num [1:26455] -Inf 0.0017 0.00189 0.00201 0.00214 ...
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ direction    : chr "<"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ cases        : num [1:1540] 0.958 0.919 0.973 0.785 0.933 ...
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ controls     : num [1:24975] 0.6604 0.026 0.1389 0.0558 0.0594 ...
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ fun.sesp     :function (thresholds, controls, cases, direction)  
  .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "roc"
  .. .. ..$ call              : language roc.default(response = results$testactual, predictor = results$pred)
  .. .. ..$ original.predictor: num [1:26515] 0.6604 0.026 0.1389 0.0558 0.0594 ...
  .. .. ..$ original.response : int [1:26515] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..$ predictor         : num [1:26515] 0.6604 0.026 0.1389 0.0558 0.0594 ...
  .. .. ..$ response          : int [1:26515] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..$ levels            : chr [1:2] "0" "1"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "roc"
 $ call              : language roc.default(response = results$testactual, predictor = results$pred)
 $ original.predictor: num [1:26515] 0.6604 0.026 0.1389 0.0558 0.0594 ...
 $ original.response : int [1:26515] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ predictor         : num [1:26515] 0.6604 0.026 0.1389 0.0558 0.0594 ...
 $ response          : int [1:26515] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ levels            : chr [1:2] "0" "1"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "roc"
```

Here is how the base package looks, just trying to do it in ggplot

[image]

EDIT: Temp solution to the problem.

```
rocy <- cbind(roc_1$sensitivities, roc_1$specificities, roc_2$sensitivities, roc_2$specificities)
rocy <- as.data.frame(rocy)
ggplot(rocy) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = V1, x = V2)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = V3, x = V4))
```

EDIT: Solution

```
library(pROC)
rocobj1 <- roc(df$actualoutcome1, data$prediction1)
rocobj2 <- roc(df$actualoutcome1, data$prediction2)
ggroc(list(call_roc_name_1 = rocobj1, call_roc_name_2 = rocobj2))
```

Comment: why don't you simply use the `sensitivities` and `specificities` of multiple your two ROCs to plot them on your own? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggROC/ggROC.pdf here you can find the code of the function `ggroc` and it is not a complicate function. I think you can customize it easily

Comment: Look at the manual page for `ggroc`: it says this function returns a `ggplot` object. You can't add two `ggplot` objects to each other---you build the object and then add layers to it

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look through the `ggroc` manual again. What I did as a backup was to extract the elements of the `roc` output and save it as a `data.frame`. It seemed to do the trick, but was thinking that there was a more elegant solution.

`rocy <- cbind(roc_1$sensitivities, roc_1$specificities, roc_2$sensitivities, roc_2$specificities)
rocy <- as.data.frame(rocy)
ggplot(rocy) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = V1, x = V2)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = V3, x = V4))`

Comment: Google brought me to a blog post by the developer (I believe) of the `pROC` package that you're using, explaining how to do this: https://xavier.robin.name/blog

Comment: Thanks followed the link and works perfect,

 `library(pROC) 
rocobj <- roc(df$actualoutcome1, data$prediction1)
rocobj2 <- roc(df$actualoutcome1, data$prediction2)

ggroc(list(call_roc_name_1 = rocobj1, call_roc_name_2 = rocobj2))`